# Objective c Parsing XML data between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I'm pretty new to objective-c and need some tips for my challenge.

I have 2 view controllers and need to show xml data retrieved from FirstViewController to the TermsViewController.

I'm successful getting user input and retrieve xml objects I need.
But don't know how to show the user name in the TermsViewController.m

Since data is downloaded async, can't figure out how to implement this for IOS 6.

Thanks in advance.

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *accessButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *codeField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *codeUser;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *nameUser;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *xmlDictionary;

@end
```

TermsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TermsViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *nameUserTerms;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "TermsViewController.h"
#import "XMLReader.h"


@interface FirstViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest;
@property NSUInteger responseStatusCode;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *theXML;

@end

@implementation FirstViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)accessButton:(UIButton *)sender {
self.codeUser = self.codeField.text;

NSString *xmlCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n"
                      "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>"
                      "<soap:Body>\n"
                      "<GetInterview xmlns='http://www.url.com/url.JCV'>\n"
                      "<Codigo>"
                      "%@"
                      "</Codigo>\n"
                      "</GetInterview>\n"
                      "</soap:Body>\n"
                      "</soap:Envelope>", self.codeUser];

NSLog(@"User code is: %@", self.codeUser);
NSLog(@"XML is: %@", xmlCode);

self.postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.url.com/url.JCV/web.url.asmx"]];

[self.postRequest setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[self.postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[self.postRequest setHTTPBody:[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[xmlCode UTF8String] length:strlen([xmlCode UTF8String])]];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.postRequest delegate:self];

if (conn) {
    NSLog(@"Connected to: %@", conn);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection Error");
}

[self.codeField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

FirstViewController.m connectionDidFinishLoading method

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

if (self.responseStatusCode == 200) {

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %lu bytes of data",[self.theXML length]);

    // Parse the XML into a dictionary
    NSError *parseError = nil;

    self.xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:self.theXML options:XMLReaderOptionsProcessNamespaces error:&parseError];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.xmlDictionary);

    //name of the candidate
    self.nameUser = [[[[[[[self.xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"Envelope"] objectForKey:@"Body"] objectForKey:@"GetInterviewResponse"] objectForKey:@"GetInterviewResult"] objectForKey:@"Obj"] objectForKey:@"ProfissionalName"] objectForKey:@"text"];

    NSLog(@"User name is: %@", self.nameUser);

    TermsViewController *nv = [[TermsViewController alloc] init];
    nv.nameUserTerms = self.nameUser;

    //check
    NSLog(@"User name stored: %@", nv.nameUserTerms);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToTerms" sender:self];

}
else {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                    message:@"bla bla."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Try again"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

TermsViewController.m

```
#import "TermsViewController.h"

@interface TermsViewController ()

@end

@implementation TermsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.nameLabel.text = self.nameUserTerms;

    //this check is returning NULL
    NSLog(@"User name: %@", self.nameUserTerms);

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `prepareForSegue` to exchange data between controllers.

Remove these lines from your code:

```
TermsViewController *nv = [[TermsViewController alloc] init];
nv.nameUserTerms = self.nameUser;
```

And put them in a method like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToTerms"]) {
        TermsViewController *nv = segue.destinationViewController;
        nv.nameUserTerms = self.nameUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: got it working. I needed to make TermsViewController *nv = segue.destinationViewController; as you said. thanks